# Are there any differences between the Wii U version and the Switch version?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, version-differences

I started playing on the Wii U, but now I also have a Switch and Zelda for that. I've made enough progress on the Wii U version that I don't want to start over, but I have enough hours left that it'd be worth it for a better experience. So far they seem identical (besides the controller, obviously). Is there any reason to start my game over on the Switch version?

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. Do you want to know the differences between the two versions of the game?

Answer (score 7):

Content-wise, the games are identical. Switch version does have a more stable framerate (more noticeable in certain later game areas) than WiiU, but if you're not super sensitive to that, it's not a major difference.
The WiiU version runs at 720p@30fps, which is the same as Switch in portable mode, but in docked mode Switch runs at 900p@30fps, which is a perceivable difference on a TV, but nothing extremely major either.
The sound quality is also better on Switch with higher quality environmental sound effects.

Whether these differences are major enough for you to start over, is up to you to decide.

Comment: I own the Switch version and I love being able to just get in bed and play it, without having a loud machine buzzing somewhere in the room, or worse yet - not working at all, because the WiiU is in another room and the signal is too weak.

Comment: 900p? That's possible?

Comment: @TimmyJim, it is rendered at 900p (why not?) and then upscaled to 1080p for output (just like 720p on the WiiU are upscaled to 1080p if that is your HDMI setting).

Comment: Hmm, playing Zelda in bed. Now there's a dangerous idea. Can you comment on one other possible difference: loading times? It's pretty slow on the older console. Is it any better on the Switch?

Comment: @Kat I can't comment on the difference, as I've only played the Switch version, but the loading times aren't bad, especially since the main issue I've always had with WiiU games was that it takes forever to start up the console and load a game, but on Switch, you don't turn it off (unless you want to), you just put it to sleep and it takes literally less than 5 seconds to go from console off to being in the game right where you left off (obviously longer if you are switching a user or something and have to reload the game from the main menu)

Comment: I've played it a bit more, and it's maybe a little faster to load when teleporting around, but not significantly. It's definitely much faster to boot up, though; you're right there.

Comment: Btw, if this answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Loading times are noticeably faster on sd carda than blu rays

Comment: This might be anecdotal, but as far as I know speedrunners use the WiiU Version because of faster loading times (don't know if Download or Disc, though).

Comment: @ian_itor I can't imagine it would be Disc.  I'm pretty sure solid state memory is far quicker than optical discs.